# How can I connect to multiple or all the sessions from the quick search results in MobaXterm?

Tags: windows, mobaxterm

Many times I have to search through all the servers in my list of sessions for a specific term in the name and then connect to all or many of them. For example, let's say that I need to find all the servers that have the 'dev' word in the name, I search for that term on the quick search bar and I get about 10 results, I haven't found a way to connect to all of them at the same time unless I put all of those servers in a specific folder then I can right click on the colder and select "connect to all sessions on this folder". But there's a problem with this approach, the problem is that I don't always have all the servers that I want to connect in a folder. Is there a simpler way to do that?